# Trouble understanding part of thereom: Every prime congruent 1 mod (4) can be written as sum of two squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been working through with great difficulty Dudley Underwood's Elementary Number Theory.

I'm having some problem understanding the proof of  a thereom regarding the sum of two squares.

I still dont see why,
[image: 5]
how this becomes:
[image: 5]
The full text is quoted here:

[image: thereom 2]

I dont understand (3) why the ranges are set between -k/2 and k/2?

and I dont understand how he derives after (5) from (3):

[image]

Comment: I've added the particular point I'm having difficulty with to the original question. Perhaps if (5) was shown as a congruence first it might help me see how from (3) he gets the two congruences shown?

Answer (score 1):

1. Many times it's more convient to deal with the range $[-n,]\,-n+1,\dots,0,1,2,\dots,n$ for modulo $2n\,[+1]$ instead of $0,1,2,3,\dots,2n\,[,2n+1]$. Especially if we want to square the elements. 
   E.g. modulo $7$ we can work with $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$.
2. Well, (3) says $r\equiv x$ and $s\equiv y\pmod k$, these imply the left congruences of (5): $x$ and $y$ are just replaced to $r$ and $s$ in the congruence. Then $r^2+s^2\equiv 0$ because, as it's written below (3), it was assumed that $x^2+y^2=kp\equiv 0\mod k$.

Comment: okay thank you I see that it s convenient to use -n to +n. But I'm still not clear why he chose -1/2k to 1/2k and not say -k to k?

Comment: I dont understand point 2. I cannot see how  rx+sy≡r^2+s^2≡0(mod k) ect.